# Automating test data generation in Performance testing-Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Kindly suggest automating Test Data generation in Jmeter is good for performance testing or not?
If i have to generate test data in large numbers, will it impact the performance testing in negative manner?
Example: If i have to generate Username, email id in large numbers and fetch them in script by using function and random variable,will Jmeter consume more time for the fetching process and will this affect the response time results?
Could anyone kindly suggest the pron's and con's of automating test data generation in performance testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as generated data fits into [Java Heap](https://crunchify.com/jvm-tuning-heapsize-stacksize-garbage-collection-fundamental/) it is fine to generate test data on-the-fly.

There should not be any impact on response time as Pre/Post processors and Timers duration is not being counted (unless you have [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) in `Generate Parent Sample` mode)

Make sure you following recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) guide to get the most of your JMeter instance(s).